# Automatic REST API generator for CRUD for Node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud, monodevelop

I have MongoDB database with multiple collections, and I want to create a CRUD REST APIs for those collections automatically using Node.js.

What is the best way?

Comment: This question requires updates: what did you already try? What were the results of debugging that solution/strategy? On stack overflow questions which are asking for a specific best tool are not permitted, because it is to help you fix the issues in your solution rather than advertising some product that may or may not continue to exist.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions.